# How to achieve a join in DQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I need to execute a simple query in ***Doctrine*** (using Symfony 3.3).

I have the "Articles" table which contains the description, and the "Packets" table, which contains the id corresponding to the Article's description.
In standard SQL this is very easy

```
SELECT p.article_id, a.description 
FROM Articles a 
JOIN Packets p 
ON p.article_id=a.id
```

How to do this in doctrine? I've almost tried everything but nothing is working! Please help

Comment: Can you detail what you tried and what error occurs ?

Comment: Can't tell much without seeing your entities and relations.

Comment: Please show us your object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try with doctrine magic methods

In controller, something like :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$packets =  $em->getRepository('NameOfYourBundle:Packets')->findByArticles($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code from Zend project, though I'd imagine it's not very different for Symfony.

With QueryBuilder in a function (such as a Repository function) somewhere:

```
// These use statements to indicate which to use in case of duplicate class names
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p'); //"p" for packet
$qb->select('p.description', 'art.id')
    ->join(
    'p.article',         // "p" for Packet Entity. "article" for property on Packet Entity
    'art',               // "art" as short name for relation
    Join::WITH,          // Join type
    'art.id = :article'  // the param on which should the join occur
)
    ->setParameter('article', $article); // Set the param with an instance

$result =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); // Get the result
```

If this is a bi-directional relationship, you can simply use the default `EntityRepository` functions provided by Doctrine.

Such as:

```
$packets = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository(Packet::class)->findBy(['article' => $article->getId()]);
```

If properly setup in the Entity, it's even easier:

```
$packets = $article->getPackets();
```